# Calling backup-buffer in after-save-hooks deletes original file

Tags: emacs

I am trying to create a backup for file after-save and before-save with the help of save hooks. Here is a code from .emacs

```
(defun force-backup-of-buffer ()                                                                                                                                                                              
    (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                             
    (setq buffer-backed-up nil)                                                                                                                                                                               
    (backup-buffer)                                                                                                                                                                                           
)                                                                                                                                                                                                             

(add-hook 'before-save-hook  'force-backup-of-buffer)                                                                                                                                                         
 (add-hook 'after-save-hook  'force-backup-of-buffer)
```

But this leads to deletion of original file. Can someone tell me why this happens?
My goal is to create two backup file everytime I save. I want to use same version control numbers as used by emacs. Hence I am using backup-buffer and not written my own hook to write file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for `backup-buffer`, which points you to the `make-backup-files` variable: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `make-backup-files` <kbd>RET</kbd>

By default, Emacs backs up by renaming the original file to the backup filename before saving the buffer to the original filename; hence your file disappearing.

I'm not sure that `backup-buffer` is really intended to be called elsewhere, however if you set it to backup by copying, you'll probably be okay.

Comment: Yes, got it.. (setq backup-by-copying t) this setting made it work the way I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to use `(let ((backup-by-copying t)) (backup-buffer))` in your code, so that it works regardless of your global setting for this variable.